# why an Associative array indexed by VARCHAR2 doesn't store more than 9 elements

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, associative-array

The associative array indexed by **VARCHAR2(32000)** store only 9 elements in this code below.
while if i used an associative array indexed by **pls_integer**, I can store more than 9 elements (in my case 15 elements) in the data structure.

So why an associative array which use VARCHAR2 index dosen't accept more than 9 elements in my example.

code:

```
declare
--TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(8) INDEX BY pls_integer;
TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(8) INDEX BY varchar2 (32000);
wtabperson tabperson ;
begin
   FOR i IN 1..15
     LOOP
        wtabperson(i) := 'A' || i;

        dbms_output.PUT_LINE(
                    'i---------> ' || 'size ' || wtabperson.last || ' content ' || 
                      wtabperson(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Here is what I got in the console:

```
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 1 content A1
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 2 content A2
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 3 content A3
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 4 content A4
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 5 content A5
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 6 content A6
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 7 content A7
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 8 content A8
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A9
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A10
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A11
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A12
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A13
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A14
[2021-06-14 11:32:59] i---------> size 9 content A15
```

**so why wtabperson.last block at 9** .

If I use this type in my example:

```
TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(8) INDEX BY pls_integer
```

I got the expected result:

```
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 1 content A1
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 2 content A2
 //
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 8 content A8
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 9 content A9
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 10 content A10
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 11 content A11
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 12 content A12
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 13 content A13
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 14 content A14
[2021-06-14 11:39:43] i---------> size 15 content A15
```

Could any one explain me this unexpected behaviour of wtabperson.last when I used an associative array with VARCHAR2 index ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're seeing that *because* the index is a string; the 15th element you add has index '15', not the number 15; and with string comparison '9' is higher than '15'. So, `last` is showing the highest *string* value, which is still '9'. As @Koen sais this is [the documented behaviour](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-33E18BC6-C0A8-456B-A47C-A4504240D962):

> For an associative array indexed by PLS_INTEGER, the first and last elements are those with the smallest and largest indexes, respectively. For an associative array indexed by string, the first and last elements are those with the lowest and highest key values, respectively.

where 'highest' and 'lowest' are based on [string comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C).

That has nothing to do with how *many* elements there are (which is clearly 15); it is only the behaviour of the index value that is affected.

If you have more elements then you'll see the `last` value change when you pass 89, as '90' is a higher value than '9', and '91' is higher than '90'; but when you pass 99 it sticks there until you reach 900. And so on.

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b9be7dea66b7eae8f09623c8decd3df7)

Answer (score 2):

You got exactly in the console what you asked for :)

*can store more than 9 elements*

Yes you can... check the counter value:

```
declare
TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(8) INDEX BY varchar2 (32000);
wtabperson tabperson ;
begin
   FOR i IN 1..15
     LOOP
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('i---------> ' || 'size ' || i || ' content ' || wtabperson(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Now... why do you only see 9 as LAST value in the collection ? That is because according to the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#GUID-33E18BC6-C0A8-456B-A47C-A4504240D962), *For an associative array indexed by string, the first and last elements are those with the lowest and highest key values, respectively.*

Since the index by is VARCHAR2, 9 is higher than 10. As a result you see the 9 which is the highest value. Index by pls_integer and it works as shown below:

```
declare
  TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(30) INDEX BY varchar2 (32000);
  TYPE tabpersonibn IS TABLE OF varchar2(30) INDEX BY pls_integer;
  wtabperson tabperson ;
  wtabpersonibn tabpersonibn ;
begin
   FOR i IN 8..11
     LOOP
        wtabperson(i) := 'by VARCHAR2' || i;
        wtabpersonibn(i) := 'by PLS_INTEGER' || i;
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('i---------> ' || 'size ' || wtabperson.last || ' content ' || wtabperson(i));
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('i---------> ' || 'size ' || wtabpersonibn.last || ' content ' || wtabpersonibn(i));
    end loop;
end;
/

i---------> size 8 content by VARCHAR28
i---------> size 8 content by PLS_INTEGER8
i---------> size 9 content by VARCHAR29
i---------> size 9 content by PLS_INTEGER9
i---------> size 9 content by VARCHAR210
i---------> size 10 content by PLS_INTEGER10
i---------> size 9 content by VARCHAR211
i---------> size 11 content by PLS_INTEGER11
```