# Why using FIRST and LAST method dosen't parse all the content of an associative array indexed by string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, associative-array

I have an associative array indexed by string that contains 12 elements.
But using FIRST and LAST method doesn't parse all the elements stored in it.

```
declare
  TYPE tabperson IS TABLE OF varchar2(8) INDEX BY varchar2 (32000);
  wtabperson tabperson ;
begin
  FOR i IN 1..12
    LOOP
        wtabperson(i) := 'A' || i;
    end loop;

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE('content of index 11: ' || wtabperson('11'));
  dbms_output.PUT_LINE('content of index 12: ' || wtabperson('12'));
  dbms_output.PUT_LINE('size of the associative array: ' || wtabperson.COUNT);

  dbms_output.PUT_LINE(' Now I would like to parse all the content of the associative array 
   ');
  for i in wtabperson.FIRST.. wtabperson.LAST
    LOOP
        dbms_output.PUT_LINE('index ' || i || ' -------------->  ' || wtabperson(i));
    end loop;
end;
```

Here is what I got in the console:

```
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] content of index 11: A11
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] content of index 12: A12
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] size of the associative array: 12
[2021-07-25 19:05:33]  Now I would like to parse all the content of the associative array 
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 1 -------------->  A1
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 2 -------------->  A2
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 3 -------------->  A3
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 4 -------------->  A4
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 5 -------------->  A5
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 6 -------------->  A6
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 7 -------------->  A7
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 8 -------------->  A8
[2021-07-25 19:05:33] index 9 -------------->  A9
```

So the associative array **indexed by string** contains 12 elements:
The index values are in this order: '1','10','11', '12', '2', '3', '4', '5','6','7','8','9'.

the wtabperson.LAST is equal to '9' and **'11' is lower than wtabperson.LAST** so why I didn't get the value of wtabperson('11') when I parsed the array using FIRST and LAST methods ?

is Using FIRST and LAST method parse only a part of the array (in case of an associative array indexed by string) ?

Why using **FIRST and LAST methods doesen't parse all the content of the associative array indexed by string** ?
[EDIT]
In This post [why-an-associative-array-doesen't-store-more-than-9-elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67968092/why-an-associative-array-indexed-by-varchar2-doesnt-store-more-than-9-elements) the question is why wtabpeson.LAST block at '9' and I got my response.

Now the question is:
Since the index value '11' is lower than '9', so why '11' is not between wtabperson.FIRST and wtabperson.LAST ? the value of wtabperson('11') is A11. so why I didn't get the value of index '11' when I parsed the array using FIRST and LAST?

Thanks

Comment: Thanks,Yes I know. could you answer this question please ? since '11' is lower than '9', so why  '11' is not between wtabperson.FIRST and wtabperson.LAST ? the value of wtabperson('11') is A11. so why I didn't get the value of index '11' when I parsed the array using FIRST and LAST?

Comment: OK, I see what you're confused about now. I'll re-open, and remove my comments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235284/discussion-between-abenamor-and-alex-poole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67968092/266304), [the documentation says](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/lnpls/plsql-collections-and-records.html#GUID-33E18BC6-C0A8-456B-A47C-A4504240D962):

> For an associative array indexed by PLS_INTEGER, the first and last elements are those with the smallest and largest indexes, respectively. For an associative array indexed by string, the first and last elements are those with the lowest and highest key values, respectively.

where 'highest' and 'lowest' are based on [string comparison](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Data-Type-Comparison-Rules.html#GUID-A114F1F4-A08D-4107-B679-323DC7FEA31C).

For your data the lowest value is '1', and the highest is '9'.

So when you do:

```
for i in wtabperson.FIRST.. wtabperson.LAST
```

with your data you are essentially doing:

```
for i in '1'..'9'
```

The loop is over the string values between those two strings, so you get the list of index keys '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'.

But it is only looking at the high and low values for the range that defines. What is is *not* doing is looping over the actual index values between first and last. The loop isn't looking at the collection, beyond getting the first/last in the loop declaration. You are (I think) expecting it to get index keys '1', '10', '11', '12', '2', ... but that isn't how it works. The loop control mechanism doesn't know that '10', '11' and '12' exist - and doesn't even know that '2' exists in your array; only that it is the next string after '1'.

If you want to loop over all the index values you can do:

```
declare
  ...
  idx varchar2(8); -- to match your key size
begin
  ...
  idx := wtabperson.FIRST; -- get first element
  while idx is not null
    loop
      dbms_output.PUT_LINE('index ' || idx || ' -------------->  ' || wtabperson(idx));
      idx := wtabperson.NEXT(idx); -- get next element
    end loop;
  END LOOP;
```

That keeps going around the loop until the index values are exhausted, in sort order; and doesn't need to refer to `last` at all.